# problem in linear algebra is unsolved though it is very fundamental ?help

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be a $ n\times m $ matrix and ***b*** be a $n \times 1$ vector(with real entries). Suppose the equation $Ax=b,x\in R^m$ admits a unique solution . Then
whether $m=n$ or $m\leq n$ .

I know that if **n=m** then it is best answer but I am in doubt that is $m\le n$ possible for it?

Comment: Do you mean for $Ax=b$ to admit a unique solution for every $b\in \mathbb{R}^n$? If so then you must have $m=n$. Have you learned about the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: yes dim = rank + nullity

Comment: Right so if $Ax=b$ admits a unique solution for some $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ then the nullity is 0 and it gives you the $m=dim=rank\le n$ condition. The inequality can be strict if $A$ is not onto for example $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

If for a matrix, say $A_{n\times m}$, we know that for each vector $b\in \mathbb{R^m}$, the system $Ax=b,x\in R^m$ admits a unique solution, the we can conclude that $rank(A)=m$. On the other hand, for each matrix of size $n\times m$,  we know that $rank(A)\leq \min\{m,n\}$.

As a result, it is concluded that $\color{red}{m\leq n}$.

Comment: matrix A is of $n\times m$

Comment: @mystak I made the revision. I hope it is now satisfactory.